# Can large data deletion affect Innodb buffer pool performance?

Tags: performance, innodb, mariadb, buffer-pool, mariadb-10.2

At the beginning of this year we lunched a lot of massive data deletions (millions of rows per week) in our production database. Also, there is an automatic integration of new data (insert/updates) of 10 to 25 .CSV files per day with a global/average size of `400MB`.

We noticed that reading performance on data even with full using of index became too slow. We have about `122GB` of daya with `60GB` of RAM and I configured `48GB` for the `Innodb buffer pool` (please check details in images).

Is the deletion affect buffer pool performance ? What is the best/fast way to resolve that issue ?

Thank you for your help.

[image: config1]

[image: detail]

**

> (UPDATED)

**

It's not really a fragmentation issue, I added a 3rd image for more information.[image: image3]

(updated)

It is not indexes (the use is about 90% - 100%) but the bad way the app is using the db model made is too bad.

Comment: How often do you `optimize table` and `analyze table`?

Comment: not really a fragmentation issue (I think), I added a 3rd image for more information.

Comment: There are still too many unknowns.  How did you do the Delete?  There are many ways; _some_ will impact the buffer_pool.

Comment: You have a huge number of indexes -- probably most are useless.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: For the future, consider changing the DELETE technique:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for the reasons outlined in [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @RickJames Delete is according to many joins and conditions (dates, countries, types...) and are different each time but with a huge amount. Thank you for the article. for using partition that will not save my day for the reason I mentioned. Also, I'm deleting in chunks to avoid overhead. Finally, I think you are right about indexes but the bad way the app is using the db model made me to optimize from the database side waiting for code correction and then remodeling them again.

Comment: @Vérace thank you is noted for next times.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted yesterday the server with making some changes in the configuration file :

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 48
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 32
innodb_read_io_threads  = 16
innodb_write_io_threads 8
```

*The buffer pool is used, no more slowness noticed until now (after some refresh).
However, still not understand the reason of the impact of deletion on the buffer pool. Thus I believe that the bad way the app is using queries via ORM is the source of this issue.*

Comment: monitor and graph your `innodb_buffer_pool` global status. Notable `*_reads` vs `*read_requests`.